# Setting up WHM nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone

I am new to server administration and I've just got a dedicated root server from Hetzner.

First I set up in Hetzner's robot DNS entries

Registered nameservers:

```
ns1.raybear.com 88.198.32.57
ns2.raybear.com 88.198.32.57
```

Under DNS entires I have

```
buzz-buzz.me pointing to 88.198.32.57 // My server IP address
```

and on my WHM I have DNS zone for buzz-buzz.me

```
; cPanel first:11.42.1.17 (update_time):1402062640 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3     hostname:hosting.raybear.com latest:11.42.1.17
; Zone file for buzz-buzz.me
$TTL 14400
buzz-buzz.me.   86400   IN  SOA ns1.raybear.com.    miskone.gmail.com.  (
                    2014060605 ;Serial Number
                    86400 ;refresh
                    7200 ;retry
                    3600000 ;expire
                    86400   )

buzz-buzz.me.   86400   IN  NS  ns1.raybear.com.
buzz-buzz.me.   86400   IN  NS  ns2.raybear.com.


buzz-buzz.me.   14400   IN  A   88.198.32.57

localhost   14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1

buzz-buzz.me.   14400   IN  MX  0   buzz-buzz.me.

mail    14400   IN  CNAME   buzz-buzz.me.
www 14400   IN  CNAME   buzz-buzz.me.
ftp 14400   IN  CNAME   buzz-buzz.me.
agent   14400   IN  A   88.198.32.57
src 14400   IN  A   88.198.32.57
platform    14400   IN  A   88.198.32.57
```

But still I have some problems accesing buzz-buzz.me, agent.buzz-buzz.me and platform.buzz-buzz.me

Also I have problem getting mails on Google account, I can send but not receive emails.

How to solve this. As I said I am completly new here and I need urgent help.:(

Comment: Hello did you manage to get it working after all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need urgent help, you need to wait a while. DNS generally takes some time to work everywhere. The domains appear to be correctly set up and resolve fine for me. Your DNS server probably has NXDOMAIN responses cached - they'll clear up on their own soon.

Comment: And how long it can take to resolve?

Comment: If I'm reading your SOA record correctly, up to a day. This only applies to users hitting DNS servers that've attempted a lookup while it was returning NXDOMAIN - if it's a new site launch, chances are you're one of the only people who *can't* get to it.

Comment: can you open all pages in your browser? www.buzz-buzz.me agent.buzz-buzz.me and platform.buzz-buzz.me?

Comment: Yes, as I noted, they all resolve fine. I see websites for all three.